# AngularJS - "Duplicates in a repeater not allowed"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a HTML `textarea` for each member of an array but it is not rendering. I have read the AngularJS docs and have tried various `track by` expressions to no avail.

The error condition arises if the user enters the same text in multiple `textareas`. It seems that Angular is using the value of the text area as a unique key. I could hack this by adding and removing an arbitrary identifier prior to the text, but this seems lame.

To be clear the textareas display the problem is after the user clicks submit (javascript only - no round trip to server) and then subsequent code renders what the user typed in.

Thanks-in-advance.

**The specific error I get is:**

```
Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed. 
Use 'track by' expression to specify unique keys. 
Repeater: openEndedQuestion in openEndedQuestions track by openEndedQuestion.id, 
Duplicate key: undefined
```

**The HTML is:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="openEndedQuestion in openEndedQuestions">
    <td width="375" style="font-size: 18px;">
        <b>{{openEndedQuestion}}</b><br>
        <textarea id="openEndedAnswer_{{$index}}" cols="80"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**The second stage HTML is:**

```
<tr ng-repeat="openEndedAnswer in openEndedAnswers">
    <td width="375" style="font-size: 18px;">
        <b>{{openEndedAnswer}}</b>
    </td>

    <td width="225">
        <span style="font-size: 35px; padding: 2px; color: #468847;" 
              ng-repeat="starIndex in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]"
              ng-click="povStarTracker.setStarRating($parent.$index, starIndex + 1)" 
              ng-class="povStarTracker.getClassForStar($parent.$index, starIndex)"></span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**The underlying JSON is:**

```
"openEndedQuestions" : [ 
    "Do you think the coach is being fair?", 
    "Should the coach give all of his players a chance to play in the games?", 
    "Should Austin say anything about this to his coach?", 
    "What could Ryan say to Austin?"
]
```

Comment: Please post code of your entire controller, as it is not clear when and how you are trying to do submit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change or add `track by` part to your ng-repeat

either use `by $index` or `by openEndedQuestion`

```
 <tr ng-repeat="oeq in openEndedQuestions track by oeq">
```

or

```
 <tr ng-repeat="oeq in openEndedQuestions track by $index">
```

Better to use second case

Also as a general rule, try not to bind to primitives in angular ( ie strings and numbers). Better solution could have been:

in the controller:

```
$scope.questions = [

 {id:1, text: "Do you think the coach is being fair?"}, 
 {id:2, text: "Should the coach give all of his players a chance to play in the games?"}, 
 {id:3, text: "Should Austin say anything about this to his coach?"}, 
 {id:4, text: "What could Ryan say to Austin?"}
]
```

and in the template:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="q in questions track by q.id">
```

See jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vittore/V5n4t/

Comment: Tried both of these. Doesn't work. Any reason you changed the name of the item from openEndedQuestion to oeq?

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi check linked jsfiddle. Just shorter name as it is used in smaller scope.

Comment: @GuidoAnselmi I improved jsfiddle to data-bind answers too.

Comment: I realized I was modifying the wrong loop with the track by thanks to your help. Well done!